# How do I add an external URL to my site's navigation menu?

Tags: links, redirect

I am new to Sitecore and I am trying to figure out how to add an `external URL link` to the `site's navigation menu`. The URL in question is supposed to link to the business's YouTube channel.

I've created a redirect object (under `/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Redirects/Redirect`) with the URL I need, but it does not appear on the dropdown menu or sitemap.

How can I make the external link appear on the menu?

Comment: This will very much depend on how you navigation components were built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out the answer. I created a new template for redirects that were declared as navigable, then created a new item with the new redirect template.